# Javascript scopes

Tags: javascript, function, scope, return

Why the below code outputs 4? and can anyone please suggest me a good article to learn javascript scopes in depth.

This piece of code returns 4 but i don't understand why?

```
(function f(){  

return f();    

function f(){
    alert(4);
};    

var f = function (){
    alert(5);
};

})();
```

But this code snippet returns 5. Why?

```
(function f(){
var f = function (){
    alert(5);
};
return f();
function f(){
    alert(4);
};
})();
```

And the last one returns 4. I didn't get it.

```
(function f(){
function f(){
    alert(4);
};
return f();
var f = function (){
    alert(5);
};
})();
```

And why the `return f();` does not call to the parent function f()?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Read about "hoisting".

Comment: Read about hoisting in javascript, and also about function declaration vs function expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with scope, it's all about what happens when [*entering an execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3).

In short, when entering an execution context (e.g. a function), variables are created and assigned a value of undefined. A variable declaration like:

```
var f = 5;
```

creates the variable *f*, but the value `5` isn't assigned until runtime and the statement is executed.

Then function declarations are processed, which effectively creates a local variable with that name and assigns the function body as its value.

Then execution begins.

More stuff happens, but that's the parts that matter here.

In the following:

```
// The optional name creates a local variable f at parse time that
// references this function. In some buggy versions of IE, it also creates
// a global f variable that references the function.
(function f(){  

  // This is the only statement in f's execution context that is executed.
  return f();    

  // This defines a function f at parse time, after the variable declaration below,
  // and overriding the initial f created 
  // above, immediately before any code is executed. It is this
  // function that is executed by the return statement
  function f(){
    alert(4);
  };    

  // The variable declaration is processed before the above function declaration
  // and before any code is run. But since f
  // already exists because of the optional name, it has no effect.
  // Since this is below the return, the assignment is never executed. 
  var f = function (){
    alert(5);
  };
})();
```

Apply to other examples.

```
(function f(){

  // Everything happens as above, but because this assignment is before the
  // return, it happens after variable function declarations, so when 
  // executed it replaces the function created by the function declaration below.
  var f = function (){
      alert(5);
  };
  return f();

  // This function is created before any code is executed, but is over ridden
  // by the assignment above at runtime
  function f(){
    alert(4);
  };
})();
```

And the last one:

```
(function f(){
  function f(){
      alert(4);
  };
  return f();

  // As with the first, this assignment never happens so
  // when f is called above, it calls the function created by 
  // the function declaration.
  var f = function (){
      alert(5);
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

following function is defined at parse time.

```
function f(){
    //code
};
```

following function is defined at runtime.

```
var f = function(){
    //code
};
```

In the first example, after parsing, value of f is supposed to alert 4. The assignment (overriding) of f is written after returning f(). Therefore the assignment never happens and final output is 4.

In the second example, after parsing, value of f is supposed to alert 4. But the assignment (overriding) of f is written before returning f(). Therefore the final output is 5.

In the third example, after parsing, value of f is supposed to alert 4. The assignment (overriding) of f is written after returning f(). Therefore the assignment never happens and final output is 4.

Comment: Note that the assignments after return statements are never executed.